# Use cookies on ZF2 redirect

Tags: cookies, zend-framework2

I'm trying to set a cookie on redirect:

```
$cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('success','1');
$response = $this->redirect()->toRoute(..., array('controller' => 'abc', 'action' => 'xyz')));
$response->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);
return $response;
```

And in the xyz action on abc controller:

```
$success = $this->getRequest()->getCookie()->success;
```

But the cookie is not being detected? How do I set a cookie and redirect?

Comment: you have to set cookie before redirecting to another controller-action.

Comment: i.e., swap your programming code in line 2 and line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
$cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('success','1');

//response1
$response = $this->getEvent()->getResponse();
$response->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);

//response2
$response = $this->redirect()->toRoute(..., array('controller' => 'abc', 'action' => 'xyz')));

return $response1;
```

`response2` is the same object as `response1` .... checkout the Redirect Controller Plugin source code to see why?

I am not sure but i think your code doesn't work becuase you need to set the `cookie` header before `location` header ...

this worked for me ,if it is still not working for you set the cookie path:

```
 $cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('success', '1', null, '/');
```

Comment: $response1 should be $response (in my solution anyway). Adding the cookie path was required for me.